# I'm creating a console based tictactoe. So for me to execute a specific function say placement of X or O inside the array using its index

Tags: javascript, console, tic-tac-toe

```
var game: () => {
    board: (firstRun: any) => void;
    place: (position: any, letter: any) => void;
    newGame: () => void;
}

var ticTacToe = game();
```

For me to execute this in console what I need to do is this

ticTacToe.place(position, letter)
Places a letter (use X or O) in the supplied position. Must be a string.

the board looks like this

Board Positions:

0 | 1 | 2

--|---|--

3 | 4 | 5

--|---|--

6 | 7 | 8

so if I enter

```
ticTacToe.place(1, "X")
```

the board will now look like this

| X |

--|---|--

|   |

--|---|--

|   |

I'm trying to simplify ticTacToe.place() to just place()

I'm fairly new to this and studying by myself :(

Comment: It does not make sense why you would want to make just a function by itself. You can set the function reference to a variable, but still not sure why it helps in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```js
const game = () => {
    board: (firstRun: any) => void;
    place: (position: any, letter: any) => void;
    newGame: () => void;
}

const ticTacToe = game();
const {place} = ticTocToe;
place(1,"x")
```

Comment: its not working, what I'm trying to accomplish is the user will be the one to type the (1,"x") so it will be blank, if they input that the X will be added in index 1 of the array. its working fine, but I dont want to type ticTacToe.place() for it to work. I want it to be like place();